# Windows 7 setup on HP pavilion g6

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, hp-pavilion, setup

I don't know how to describe the problem on the title.

Few days back I bought a used HP Pavilion G6. It had the OEM installed windows 7(I didn't remember which edition it was). After buying the laptop I did a reinstallation of windows 7 professional on that machine with the help of an dvd that I don't know from where I got. Everything was great. The windows was activated with OEM key and on the windows system details page hp support was present and Hp theme got installed during the setup. But couple of days after I needed to install some adobe software which required windows 10. So I downloaded the en_int_x64  ISO from microsoft website. Rufus were used to create the boothable media. I started the update by running setup.exe. On the process I made the mistake of selecting "download all the required updates and drivers". There was a power down during the update process. So when I stared the laptop again It have revert back to windows 7 and the product key got deactivated.

So I did a clean installation of windows 7 with the hope of windows will be automatically activated by bios during the installation process. But I got nothing, not even the manufacturer details on the system details page. Also no theme was installed by the bios.

So I tried again to install windows. But this time pc was showing a error saying booth disk is corrupted. So I downloaded Windows 7 ISO. Now this time setup was showing another error saying that windows cant be installed MBR disk on a uefi system. So I converted it and Installed windows for two times but no activation, no manufacturer details. Another thing, During the first setup I have choosen ultimate edition, on the selection menu. from that time windows is not giving me the option to select another edition of windows.

So how can I get out of this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any BIOS being able to hold Windows Activation keys. You should have a sticker on the bottom of your notebook that specifies your OEM Windows Activation Key. If there is not a sticker the party you purchased this device from will have this key. If they don't contact Microsoft and ask why (you paid for it, theoretically).

You need to determine (from the OEM) which version of Windows 7 was installed. The key is generated for the specific version of windows (excluding possible volume licensing versions).

As to the MBR issue, it sure sounds to me you need to delete all partitions on the drive and start clean. [This site can offer you the details to delete the partitions.](https://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/tip/Using-Diskpart-to-create-extend-or-delete-a-disk-partition) NOTE: just enter nospam@microsoft.com for the email prompt.